# Volley POST Request: 'com.android.volley.ClientError'

Tags: android, api, android-studio, postman, android-volley

I am making a Video Player App and want to use 'open subtitles api' to download the subtitles from within the app same like the 'VLC media player' does. When triggering the download API, Volley is giving this error [image: screen shot] when giving a POST request with three headers and one parameters. The API is working properly and it is getting triggered when I run my app. I have tried and tested on postman and it is working fine and giving this response [image: postman screenshot] however I am not getting this response in android app instead "com.android.volley.ClientError" and I am stuck here.

This is my code:

```
 public void sendDownloadRequest()  {
    
    StringRequest downloadRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, downloadurl,  new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "Response: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error from Download: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> bodyParams = new HashMap<>();
            bodyParams.put("file_name", "batman");
            return bodyParams;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> headerParams = new HashMap<>();
            headerParams.put("Authorization", "My Auth Key");
            headerParams.put("Api-Key", "My Api Key");
            headerParams.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return headerParams;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(downloadRequest);
```

This is the request body of postman

[image: here]

I thought that it could be the error of the parameters but I am already giving the right params
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the `Authorization` type is `Bearer Token` you also have to add the prefix `Bearer` to your `My Auth Key`

Comment: Authorization is working fine because my API is getting triggered, but the response I am getting is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the `getBodyContentType()` as well,

```
...

public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
}

protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

...
```

and remove the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Removed the **Content-Type header** and Overrided the **getBodyContentType()** but still same error!

Comment: Upload a screenshot of the request body in postman to the question